# unable to install python swagger client using terminal

Tags: python, installation, terminal, swagger, swagger-codegen

Trying to install generated swagger client (from https://editor.swagger.io/)
and failing miserably.

i change to the correct directory and type this into terminal:
`python setup.py install`

It begins successfully, but the final line shows an error:
`error: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: 'dist/swagger_client-1.0.0-py3.6.egg`

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT!

The egg file it errors on had been copied into the correct location but .egg files are zip files, so it needed to be unzipped in order to be recognised by the Python import function.

so i just used the unzip command in the CLI and it worked like a charm.
some sources online say you need to rename your .egg file to a .zip file before unzipping, but i didnt find that to be necessary.